# EMF working with Virgo

Tags: eclipse, emf, eclipse-virgo

I'm trying to use EMF in a Virgo container. In my POM I added the following dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.emf</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.eclipse.emf.ecore</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.0-v20120911-0500</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.emf</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.eclipse.emf.common</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.0-v20120911-0500</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.eclipse.core.runtime</artifactId>
    <version>3.6.0.v20100505</version>
</dependency>
```

Although when I start my Server I get the following exception:

```
[2013-04-29 15:29:56.880]  TCP Connection(6)-127.0.0.1 <DE0002E> Installation of bundle 'xxx' version '0.0.1' failed. org.eclipse.virgo.nano.deployer.api.core.DeploymentException: commit failed
    at org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.install.pipeline.stage.resolve.internal.CommitStage.process(CommitStage.java:40)
    at org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.install.pipeline.internal.StandardPipeline.doProcessGraph(StandardPipeline.java:62)
    at org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.install.pipeline.internal.CompensatingPipeline.doProcessGraph(CompensatingPipeline.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.install.pipeline.stage.AbstractPipelineStage.process(AbstractPipelineStage.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.install.pipeline.internal.StandardPipeline.doProcessGraph(StandardPipeline.java:62)
    at org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.install.pipeline.stage.AbstractPipelineStage.process(AbstractPipelineStage.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.deployer.core.internal.PipelinedApplicationDeployer.driveInstallPipeline(PipelinedApplicationDeployer.java:359)
    at org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.deployer.core.internal.PipelinedApplicationDeployer.doInstall(PipelinedApplicationDeployer.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.deployer.core.internal.PipelinedApplicationDeployer.install(PipelinedApplicationDeployer.java:140)
    at org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.deployer.core.internal.PipelinedApplicationDeployer.deploy(PipelinedApplicationDeployer.java:253)
    at org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.deployer.management.StandardDeployer.deploy(StandardDeployer.java:52)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.ConvertingMethod.invokeWithOpenReturn(ConvertingMethod.java:167)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MXBeanIntrospector.invokeM2(MXBeanIntrospector.java:96)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MXBeanIntrospector.invokeM2(MXBeanIntrospector.java:33)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MBeanIntrospector.invokeM(MBeanIntrospector.java:208)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.PerInterface.invoke(PerInterface.java:120)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MBeanSupport.invoke(MBeanSupport.java:264)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:836)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:762)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1454)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:74)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1295)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1387)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:818)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:303)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:159)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:155)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:535)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:790)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:649)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
Caused by: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Failed to start bundle 'org.eclipse.emf.ecore' version '2.8.0.v20120606-0717'
    at org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.userregion.internal.quasi.StandardQuasiFramework.startBundle(StandardQuasiFramework.java:386)
    at org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.userregion.internal.quasi.StandardQuasiFramework.startBundles(StandardQuasiFramework.java:376)
    at org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.userregion.internal.quasi.StandardQuasiFramework.commit(StandardQuasiFramework.java:365)
    at org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.install.pipeline.stage.resolve.internal.CommitStage.process(CommitStage.java:38)
    ... 41 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exception in org.eclipse.emf.ecore.plugin.EcorePlugin$Implementation.start() of bundle org.eclipse.emf.ecore.
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:734)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:381)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.start(AbstractBundle.java:300)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.start(AbstractBundle.java:292)
    at org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.userregion.internal.quasi.StandardQuasiFramework.startBundle(StandardQuasiFramework.java:384)
    ... 44 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.plugin.RegistryReader.readRegistry(RegistryReader.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.plugin.EcorePlugin$Implementation.start(EcorePlugin.java:557)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run(BundleContextImpl.java:711)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:702)
    ... 49 common frames omitted
```

And I have the feeling the Activator is trying to do something assuming an Eclipse plugin environment while there isn't one. Has anyone used EMF successfully in a Virgo bundle?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right because EMF think is running in a Eclipse environment. We have integrate EMF with Virgo following the next steps:

1. Create a bundle wrapper with a folder named lib and put into this
   folder the EMF jars. In our case, we put the libraries:
   org.eclipse.emf.common-2.7.0.v20110128-1409.jar,
   org.eclipse.emf.ecore-2.7.0.v20110128-1409.jar and
   org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi-2.6.0.v20110126-1727.jar
2. Add these libraries in your bundle classpath in MANIFEST.MF
3. Re-export the EMF packages in your MANIFEST.MF
4. Create an Activator class and set the registry. The code is:

   ```
   @Override
   public void start(BundleContext arg0) throws Exception {
       Properties props = System.getProperties();
       props.setProperty("org.eclipse.emf.ecore.EPackage.Registry.INSTANCE",
               "org.eclipse.emf.ecore.impl.EPackageRegistryImpl");

   }

   @Override
   public void stop(BundleContext arg0) throws Exception {
       Properties props = System.getProperties();
       props.remove("org.eclipse.emf.ecore.impl.EPackageRegistryImpl");

   }
   ```

Finally, the MANIFEST.MF would be something like that:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-Version: 2.7.0
Bundle-Name: EMF-Wrapper
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-SymbolicName: emf-wrapper
Bundle-ClassPath: .,
 lib/org.eclipse.emf.common-2.7.0.v20110128-1409.jar,
 lib/org.eclipse.emf.ecore-2.7.0.v20110128-1409.jar,
 lib/org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi-2.6.0.v20110126-1727.jar
Export-Package: your.activator.package,
 org.eclipse.emf.common;version="2.7.0.v20110128-1409",
 org.eclipse.emf.common.archive;version="2.7.0.v20110128-1409",
 org.eclipse.emf.common.notify;version="2.7.0.v20110128-1409",
 org.eclipse.emf.common.notify.impl;version="2.7.0.v20110128-1409",
 org.eclipse.emf.common.util;version="2.7.0.v20110128-1409",
 org.eclipse.emf.ecore;version="2.7.0.v20110128-1409",
 org.eclipse.emf.ecore.impl;version="2.7.0.v20110128-1409",
 org.eclipse.emf.ecore.plugin;version="2.7.0.v20110128-1409",
 org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource;version="2.7.0.v20110128-1409",
 org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.impl;version="2.7.0.v20110128-1409",
 org.eclipse.emf.ecore.util;version="2.7.0.v20110128-1409",
 org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi;version="2.6.0.v20110126-1727",
 org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.impl;version="2.6.0.v20110126-1727",
 org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.util;version="2.6.0.v20110126-1727",
 org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xml.namespace;version="2.7.0.v20110128-1409",
 org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xml.type;version="2.7.0.v20110128-1409",
 org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xml.type.internal;version="2.7.0.v20110128-1409",
 org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xml.type.util;version="2.7.0.v20110128-1409"
Bundle-Activator: your.activator.package.Activator
Import-Package: org.osgi.framework;version="[1.7.0,1.7.0]"
```

Answer (score 1):

Following the above inspiration I created this wrapper which does the job. Note that I am not including a copy of the EMF libs but just bringing them in through a maven dependency.

https://github.com/tarelli/emfwrapper